# How to open a new tab and opening a url in seleniums remote driver using perl language

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver

i am using Selenium::Remote::Driver module,i want to open the new tab in firefox browser using perl language, can you please suggest me which method i have to use.

```
**tabsprogram.pl**


use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new();
 if(defined $driver)
{

  $driver->get("https://www.google.co.in/");
  $driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(40000);
  $driver->find_element('body','tag_name')->send_keys(KEYS->{'Ctrl','t'});# the element is find but tab is not clicked
}
```

But i did not get any error mesage,the new tab is also not opened and driver is quit.
    please help me....

Answer (score 3):

I did this to get it working

```
  $driver->send_keys_to_active_element(KEYS->{'command_meta'}, 't');
```

But then I'm on a Mac and Firefox wants Meta-T to open a new tab

If you do

```
perldoc -l Selenium::Remote::WDKeys
```

to get the location of the module then look into it it has things like

```
use constant KEYS => {
    'null'       => "\N{U+E000}",
    'cancel'     => "\N{U+E001}",
    'help'       => "\N{U+E002}",
    'backspace'  => "\N{U+E003}",
    'tab'        => "\N{U+E004}",
    'clear'      => "\N{U+E005}",
    'return'     => "\N{U+E006}",
    'enter'      => "\N{U+E007}",
    'shift'      => "\N{U+E008}",
    'control'    => "\N{U+E009}",
```

So you might need to use the word 'control' rather than 'Ctrl' and you can pass 't' without using KEYS->

These are the control keys used as per the link in the module http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/element/:id/value

Comment: yes it is working for me.. i am using this code              $driver->send_keys_to_active_element(KEYS->{'control'}, 't');Thank u